# Expect spawn: No such file or directory error

Tags: bash, expect

I am writing an Expect script that remotes to a server "server2" and executes fileexists.sh that will find if file exists at a particular location.

Bash script - fileexists.sh is as follows:

```html
#!/bin/bash

if [ -s $1 ]; then 
   echo "non empty file exists."
else 
   echo "File doesnot exist or is empty."
```

Expect script - expec is as follows:

```html
#!/usr/bin/expect
set username [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set hostname [lindex $argv 2]
set rfile [lindex $argv 3]
set prompt "$username* ~]$ "

spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$hostname

expect {
    timeout {
        puts "\n\nConnection timed out"
        exit 1
    }

    "*assword:" {
        send "$password\r"
    }
}

expect {
    "$prompt" {
        puts "Logged in successfully.
    }
}

spawn ./fileexists.sh $rfile

set lineterminationChar "\r"
expect {
       $lineterminationChar   { append output $expect_out(buffer);exp_continue}
       eof                    { append output $expect_out(buffer)}
       }
puts $output
```

When i call the expect script with ./expec user pass server2 /apps/bin/file.p I get output as  "File doesnot exist or is empty." although the file exists at its location on server2.

i checked using expect:
if {[file exists $rfile]} { puts "file exists" }

And output i get is "file exists".

Seems to be something with spawn that I am unable to figure out.

Comment: Does the shell script exist on the remote machine, or only on your local machine? Because the way you're calling it, it's only checking the size of the file on your local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check on the remote host, do this (I assume you are logging in to a linux machine, or a machine with GNU `stat`): untested

```
send -- "stat -c '%s' '$rfile'\r"

expect {
    -re {\r\n(\d+)\r\n} {
        puts "$rfile exists with size $expect_out(1,string)"
    }
    -gl {*No such file or directory*} {
         puts "$rfile does not exist"
    }
}

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```